# inverse image of a function in topology

Tags: general-topology

I really got confused when I study continuous mapping in topology. one of proof uses following statement. Can you please help me understand this.

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau_1)$ be topological spaces with $\tau_1 \subset \tau$

Let $f$ be a function from $(X,\tau)$ into $(X,\tau_1)$, then from given information, how do we know that $f^{-1}(U) = U$ where $U \in \tau_1$ and $f^{-1}(\cdot)$ is an inverse image?

Thanks,

Comment: We do not know that, as it in general not true.

Comment: That is almost always false so unless more context is given it's unanswerable

Comment: Assume $f^{-1}(U)=U$ and $\tau_1$ is $T_1$, then $f=\text{id}$. Why? If $f(x)=y$ and $x\ne y$, then we find a neighborhood $O$ of $y$ not containing $x$, this leads to $x\in f^{-1}(O)$ which is a contradiction. - But it is true that $\tau_1 \subset \tau$ if and only if $\text{id} \colon (X,\tau)\to (X,\tau_1)$ is continuous.

Comment: Sorry, guys i did not notice the function is an identity function.